# How to use css nth-child to target columns in a fixed grid size?

Tags: html, css

In html/css, I have boxes wrapping in a parent box. We know for sure it will have 4 columns exactly.

This is what I have so far

https://jsfiddle.net/f1cow40z/1/

```
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.Parent {
  width:398px;
  font-size:0;
}
.Tile {
  display:inline-block;
  width:92px;
  height:92px;
  background-color:orange;
  color:white;
  font-size:12px;
}
.Tile:nth-child(2n), .Tile:nth-child(3n), .Tile:nth-child(4n) {
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

The parent width is 398 because each tile is 92 in width and I want a gutter size of 10. So 92*4 + 10+10+10 = 398.

However I want to add that gutter space (margin-right of 10px) only on the tiles on the first, 2nd and third columns, using something that works with IE11. So the nth-child css.

How can I use that to only target the first 3 columns only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do the correct math and use this

```
.Tile:nth-child(4n - 1),
.Tile:nth-child(4n - 2),
.Tile:nth-child(4n - 3)
```

```css
.Parent {
  width: 398px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.Tile {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 92px;
  height: 92px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.Tile:nth-child(4n - 1),
.Tile:nth-child(4n - 2),
.Tile:nth-child(4n - 3) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent">
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
  <div class="Tile">A</div>
</div>
```